# Auto create rows after X columns WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, row

I create the page "articles" on my site with WordPress and Bootstrap. I'm looking for that : all 3 articles (columns), a new "row" separates everything. This would make a row, article 1, article 2, article 3, end of row, new row, article 4, article 5...

My theme is a starter theme for WordPress : Underscore

Here is my code for generating article summaries (on content.php file):

This works perfectly but the content is generated endlessly (infinite loop).

[Here the result on browser](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504813612-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-21-45-58.png)

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $i = 1; while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blog-resume">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                        <div class="featured-image-blog" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>')"></div>
                    </a>
                </header>
                <div class="article-resume text-center">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="posted-on">Posté le <?php echo the_date() ?></p>
                    <p class="resume-article"><?php echo the_content() ?></p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <?php if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) { echo '</div><div class="row">'; } ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

I think it's index.php file where content.php il call, here the content of index.php :

```
<div class="blog-part">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="text-center"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <?php
        endif;

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        /*
        * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
        * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
        * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
        */
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif; ?>

</div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- blog-part -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Here the CSS of .blog-resume

```
    .blog-resume {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .blog-resume > article {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use some sort of a grid system. Have a look at Bootstrap and CSS Grids.

Comment: I specified in the message that I use Bootstrap :)

Comment: Well then, look up the documentation for using it :) Before you post here, it's expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. All the information you need is in the Bootstrap docs. Give it a try and if you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I have updated my post to show you what I have tried, which does not work : infinite loop :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to start and stop new rows with groups of 3 columns simply test the index (or a counter) in your loop of articles with PHPs modulo operator to determine if it's divisible by 3.

```
<?php if($i % 3 == 0)  { 
  // do something here like start and stop new rows 
} ?>
```

In the above example $i would be the number (starting at 1 not 0) of the current index in your loop. So if you're displaying your 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc. article, you can then add the code to open and close new rows.

However you shouldn't really need to do this. Bootstrap columns should be allowed to wrap.  Cordoning off your columns to always have 3 per row kind of kills the responsive element that bootstrap provides.

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I found inspiration to try something (I updated my message) but the generated content never stops (infinite loop)

Comment: I did not see any error message, the browser runs endlessly. I have 4 fictitious articles, a first row is created with the 3 articles in it, a second row is created with the last article inside, then a new line with the first 3 articles, a new one with the remaining article etc. ...

Comment: and if you remove the conditional line `<?php if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) { echo '</div><div class="row">'; } ?>` it shows the correct number of items (although maybe not in the row format you prefer)?

Comment: If I just remove this line, I no longer have the correct formatting and the infinite loop is always present, I post you some screenshots

Comment: The infinite loop is a problem with how you're iterating through your wordpress posts object then and has nothing to do with that line.  You need to correct how you're looping through your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You already use the bootstrap `col-xx-x` classes so let them do the hard work for you!

You are using `col-sm-4` in your code, so just take out your loop.

Here is what your code should look like:

**index.php** - this is where your loop is, so add the outer class (i.e. `row`) outside your while loop.

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

[... your header code here...]

<div class="row">  <?php /* ADD YOUR ROW CLASS HERE!! */ ?>

    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();     
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    ?>

</div> <?php /* END ROW CLASS */

[...post navigation, etc here... ]

endif; ?>
```

**content.php** - don't loop again in here! Only display the contents of the current post

```
<div class="col-sm-4 blog-resume">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                <div class="featured-image-blog" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>')"></div>
            </a>
        </header>
        <div class="article-resume text-center">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></a></h2>
            <p class="posted-on">Posté le <?php echo the_date() ?></p>
            <p class="resume-article"><?php echo the_content() ?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

**Update:**

For the issue you are having with one article on its own row:

Bootstrap uses `float` to line up the elements, and what's happening is that your 2nd article is longer than the 3rd, and the 4th article is getting "caught" by it when it tries to float all the way over to the left.

I don't use Bootstrap so I thought something was interfering with your Bootstrap classes, but it turns out that is actually how Bootstrap works. I assumed it would handle new rows properly... apparently not!

What you need to do is add a `clear` to the first element of each row so it won't get blocked by any in the previous row.

Add the following to your CSS (make sure to include it *after* Bootstrap's css)

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }  
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear: left;
  }  
}
```

I think the name of the `row` class is whats confusing you... it might sound like you need to put every 3 articles into their own `row`, but actually the `row` class here just acts like a container. Bootstrap will automatically display all the articles that are in that container as rows with the appropriate number of articles in each, depending on what size `col` class you have chosen.

The advantage of this is that you can specify something like `class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3"`, which means Bootstrap will automatically put 4 articles in a row on large screens and just 3 on smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought I would do as you say but look at the behavior of the last two articles on the screenshot below : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504813897-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-21-51-04.png

Comment: Yes, because I can see in your code inspector that you are still using `col-sm-4`. Can you post a link to the live site?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not on line yet ... Want to see the result with "col-sm-3 col-lg-4" instead? http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504814222-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-21-56-36.png

Comment: You don't need `col-sm-3 col-lg-4`... just `col-sm-3`. I updated your code to be exactly what you should have- replace your `<div class="row">`....`</div>` with the code from my answer and show me the results :)

Comment: Also, can you update your question with the CSS for `.blog-resume`? That could be interfering with the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Here the famous magnifier, always present ^^ http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504814605-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-22-03-00.png I put the contents of the blog-resume class :)

Comment: Ahhh maybe it's because of the file itself : content.php You do not think ? My theme is underscore

Comment: This is in content.php? Then that would explain it! Show us the code where you include the content file - you must be looping there too, and thats causing a problem! It would also explain why you have so many `row` classes... I couldn't figure out where the multiple queries where coming from? Can you update with the code calling content.php, and we'll get this sorted :)

Comment: I am so sorry to have forgotten to specify this ... I believe that content.php is called in index.php, I put the content in my initial message

Comment: Yes, that was rather important... :) I've updated my answer, try that and see.

Comment: This is the result : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504816769-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-22-39-02.png
The last article is always misplaced :o

Comment: Ok well at least your html looks right now :) not sure why the Bootstrap classes aren't working, that should fix the layout problem. Can you show the css in the inspector for the 'div class="col-sm-3 blog-resume">' ?

Comment: Of course, "et voilà" : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/36/4/1504817722-capture-d-ecran-2017-09-07-a-22-54-59.png

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer - make sure to check both the content.php and the new CSS I added. I don't use Bootstrap myself so I assumed it handled the clearing of floats on new rows... it turns out it doesn't! So try the CSS I added to make it clear the rows. Also, you were right all along with `col-sm-4` - When it wasn't working, I assumed that maybe col-sm-3 would work.  Sorry :) But the floats and the double looping were actually the problem, so my updated answer should hopefully fix that... try it now and let me know how you get on this time!